# Remove ldap auth in htaccess for specific hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, passenger

I have a Rails server (Passenger/Apache) that is running for all intents and purposes, LDAP authentication.

```
<Directory "/railsapp/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Require valid-user
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

I use the REMOTE_USER variable in conjunction with a local database for user authentication. However, I have a set of special hosts that need to be able to wget a route from this rails application. The application already has the logic to not check REMOTE_USER for these routes.

Possible solutions are configuring a .htaccess for a special user and password to use for authentication, but this would grant access to the application. Instead, I was thinking of whitelisting the mostly static list of hosts such that `Require valid-user` would not apply to these hosts.

How would I setup /railsapp/public/.htaccess and/or the vhost.conf for this?

I tried (in .htaccess)

```
allow from myhost.mydomain.com
```

and restarted apache, but I still get 401 Authorization Required when trying from myhost.

How would I go about avoiding the authentication I put on my webapp? Solutions need not be restricted to how I'm trying to go about this, but I absolutely need the LDAP REMOTE_USER for my primary application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [Satisfy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy) directive

```
Satisfy Any
```

as well as

```
allow from myhost.mydomain.com
```

to your .htaccess.